# Compiler doesn´t know std::to_string ? (C++, even after patch)

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, tostring

Stop ! before you mark this as duplicate question: 
The problem is that my compiler doesn´t know std::to_string(): I included string and after some research I found out that its probably a MinGW(yes, I´m on Windows) bug and so I **tried this patch** (http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string) but it just won´t work :( Do you know other patches or other things that could cause the problem?

```
error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
a = b + std::to_string(12);
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::string a = "Hallo Welt.";
  std::string b("Hallo Welt.");
  std::string c(50,'i');

  a = b + c;
  a = b + std::to_string(12);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: GCC version is?

Comment: my version is 4.9.2

Comment: Update your compiler.

Comment: Are you compiling with this flag `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: It is, but I have very bad experience to get MinGW working and a patch would be much better :D

Comment: @Galik thank you very much, it solved my problem :D

Comment: @JavaProgrammer.002 Do not vandalize your questions.